# readyState 4 - redirect url is that possible?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was wondering if it is possible when u have readyState == 4, to redirect to a page..

```
    //load the send form
    if (sendRequest) {
        sendRequest.open("POST", urlRequest, true);
        sendRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        sendRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        sendRequest.onreadystatechange = displayStatus;
        sendRequest.send(sendData);
    } else {
        alert("fails"); //alert if request fails
    }
}

function displayStatus() {
    if (sendRequest.readyState == 4) {
        alert("send");
    // redirect to thank you page? 


    } else {
        alert("send fails"); 

} //end readyState
```

}

i am not going to get 200

so on readyState 4 , i want to redirect to a page, 
after the form is sended i want to redirect to a page.
on php mail function, `<?php header(location: "url"); ?>` is not working 
so i really need to have it in ajax/javascript...

currently it just not working.
any suggestion?

Comment: Can you not do a server-side redirect?

Comment: I presume this is about handling the result of an XMLHttpRequest, so a server-side redirect won't work

Comment: when you say it's not working, does anything happen? Are there Javascript errors?

Comment: pointy this is correct, its about the xmlhttprequest, 
on the readystate is 4, i get the alert message,
but the redirection nothing happens, as you said, i can assume the redirection just wont work, i am going to read Quincy suggestion.. mayb that will help..

Comment: Quincy's suggestion is pretty straight forward and something I would also recommend it but just take overhead into consideration, you don't want to load an extra library just for one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you J.Romero. With your input i have trace down the problem and construct the script a bit different.

It was not a cross domain issue - those settings are set properly. 
Alert box is correct and the sendRequest is global, so all functions can call it.

This lead to only 1 fault, and that is in the form. 
had `onSubmit="return checkForm(this);" action=""` 
It should be `onSubmit="checkForm(this); return false;" action=""`

with the onSubmit event return a value of false, so the form doesn't submit as usual.
and constructing the js and ajax properly to finalize the send form.
validate the form -> when ok -> prepare the form -> call ajax -> all valid -> send form -> redirect to thank you page.

Thank all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

do u mean you want to redirect once the ajax succeed?
If yes, try using jquery ajax() function and add the redirect code as the success callback

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

post() is an easier alternative
http://docs.jquery.com/Post

Answer (score 0):

Is your code inside the `sendRequest.onreadystatechange` callback? Even if you don't anticipate a 200 return it should be within that callback.

Try

```
sendRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
  //DEBUG
  alert("ready state change: "+ sendRequest.readyStat);
  if (sendRequest.readyState == 4) {
    alert("form sended");
    window.location = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
  }
}
```

And Pointy is right, Server side won't work for two main reasons, one the header has already been sent for the page making the request and because the page requested is AJAX so only the requested page will change not the current one.

[EDIT]
Have you checked the error console? Also, does this page involve frames by chance?

[EDIT 2]

I've built a jsbin for this and it does work on Firefox and Chrome... http://jsbin.com/umufi4/2/edit

I'm fairly certain that it's not the location change you have issues with if you use 'http://' infront of it but how your sendRequest is constructed. Here are some errors I've caught some I'm sure are related to jsbin and remote access but if they exists on your end it might be preventing it from getting to `window.location`

ERRORS:
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://jromero.me/. Origin http://jsbin.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
jromero.meFailed to load resource

I've got a few questions:

1. Is this a cross domain request?
2. Do you get the "send" alert box?
3. Is sendRequest a global variable?

Comment: the code is inside the

sendRequest.onreadystatechange = checkStatus;

function checkStatus() {
if (sendRequest.readyState == 4) {
  alert("message"); // on success
  window.location = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
}

there are no errors , and the page is involving php with forms in custom wordpress theme i am building...

the form is send, i am receiving the e-mails, everything is working fine.

just want to throw out a redirection to thank you page when everything is success.

and you're right, i dont want to write new codes for a single function... there must be a easier workaround this?

Comment: is there anyway you can post more of the actual code involved in this? window.location is not a hard thing to execute. and if I remember correctly you said you do get the alert right? One last thing, I hope you are using 'http://' infront of 'mywebsite.com'. Can you confirm?

Comment: i updated the code and yes i am using http://www.  etc. even tried window.location.href as i was worried i might made a typo. it just not getting fired