# Not able to call the API and redirect at the same time

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirect, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to call an API with XMLHttpRequest and then on success status I am trying to redirect it to the next page but redirection is working and the call is not working and If I remove the redirection the call works..

I am not sure if I cannot redirect while calling the API or I am doing something wrong so please check and advise

This is the code I am writing in the success of the AJAX call.

```
if (response.status === true) {
  var api = "https://api-voice.solutionsinfini.com/v1/?api_key=****&method=dial.click2call&output=xml&caller=****&receiver=" + sessionStorage.fullNumber;

  // Calling the API
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", api);
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('myModalCallback').style.display = 'none';
      window.location.href = "/anotherpage";
    }
  };
  xhttp.send();
  document.getElementById('myModalCallback').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Your redirection works when you get the status 200, so your api also works, so where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that by putting the redirection inside the onreadystatechange function the api is not working and if I put outside then the redirection is not working.. the api is supposed to generate a phone call but that is not working with the redirection

Comment: Have you read this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183178/readystate-4-redirect-url-is-that-possible

Comment: Could you use jQuery instead?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect, that the code is quite okay, but you don't get a 200 response back. You could debug in two ways:

1. Use the following code to check the response code from your api server (please note I changed the API endpoint, and this code works perfectly)

```
var api = "//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?";

// Calling the API
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", api);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
    {
      console.log('yass, 200 response');
      document.getElementById('myModalCallback').style.display = 'none';
      window.location.href = "/otherpage";
    } else if (xhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      // got a bad response
      console.log('ouch, '+xhttp.status+' response');
    } else {
      console.log('ready state change',xhttp.readyState);
    }
};
xhttp.send();
document.getElementById('myModalCallback').style.display = 'none';
```

2. check in your browser's network tab what response you get from the API
   [image: use network tab to inspect XHR responses]

I really suggest to use something like jQuery's ajax call (**which works well across browsers**), instead of using directly an XMLHttpRequest object: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

This line is asynchronous because DOM changes are queued up so the browser can updates them together:

```
document.getElementById('myModalCallback').style.display = 'none';
```

The redirect happens before browser updates DOM. To solve this, you need to put redirect at the end of the event loop. One way of doing it is to use setTimeout.

Checkout this answer for more explanation on DOM updating queue: [Update the DOM vs Rerender the View In Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229693/update-the-dom-vs-rerender-the-view-in-angular/31229816#31229816)

Event loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 1):

May be you wait from your code that getElementById('myModalCallback') will be disapear before redirect? It's may be like it's dont disapear before redirect. If you need to view "display:none" effect before redirect you must do redirect in some timeout.

Something like this:

```
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById('myModalCallback').style.display = 'none';
  window.setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.href = "/anotherpage";
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: how can I be sure that within 1 sec the api task will be completed?

Comment: 1 sec - timeout only for react of interface if you need. When (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) is true - your call already finished and return HTTP status 200. JavaScript can blocked user interface while it's executing. Timeout only use for give time to browser execute command display:none in interface if you need in that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting a `console.log('xhttp', xhttp)` on the first line of your `onreadystatechange` function to check your getting back what your expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using also the new syntax for XMLHttpRequest?

```
function onResponse () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", onResponse);
oReq.open("GET", "https://httpbin.org/get");
oReq.send();
```